# Use Apache HttpClient with caching enabled as Jersey 2 client

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-client

How can I use a custom configured Apache HttpClient with Jersey Client 2?

HttpClient with Caching ([from apache docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/caching.html))

```
CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
        .setMaxCacheEntries(1000)
        .setMaxObjectSize(8192)
        .build();
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(30000)
        .setSocketTimeout(30000)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient cachingClient = CachingHttpClients.custom()
        .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .build();
```

Using Apache Http in general works by setting

```
protected ClientConfig getClientConfig() {
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        config.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);

        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

        config.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, connectionManager);

        final ApacheConnectorProvider connector = new ApacheConnectorProvider();
        config.connectorProvider(connector);

        return config;
    }
```

But how to use custom http client config like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ApacheHttpClientBuilderConfigurator](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/connectors/apache-connector/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/ApacheHttpClientBuilderConfigurator.java). So you can do:

```
config.register(new ApacheHttpClientBuilderConfigurator() {
   public HttpClientBuilder configure(HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
      return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
   }
});
```

See [the example](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/24a0f65b3b4b7a79ff2553c85baf7427ef554cf9/connectors/apache-connector/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/AuthTest.java#L577).

The Apache caching client is not properly supported at the moment. You may return CachingHttpClientBuilder from the method, but the HttpClientBuilder does not have getters to see what is already set, so you need to set everything from scratch.